# executing code every 24h, but only if app is opened

Tags: java, android

I want to execute specific code in my app every 24h.

I know how to use AlarmManager but problem is I don't want that code to be executed if app isn't running.

I want it to be executed when app starts but only if 24h has passed after last execution.

It doesn't matter if more 24h has passed

For example if user opens my app for the first time code will execute. If it opens it again after 20min nothing will happen. if it opens it after 24h or more code will be executed.

Comment: Do you only want the code to execute only when it is opened? Or if I say left it running for 25 hours, would it execute it in that time?

Comment: only when app is opened, there is no need that my app stays opened for 24h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save to a file, the time the program was started.  You can check this before writing to see how long it has been.

Note: if there is a task you want to run at least 24h apart, you really want the last time the task was performed. e.g. if the application is opened every 8h you still want it to run.

Comment: App is downloading data from server. That data is being updated every 24h. There is no need to download new data if app isn't running.

Comment: Even though it might update every day, it could update any time in that day. It should be able to determine from data downloaded which day it is for. If it is more than 24h old (which could be << 24h since it downloaded) it asks for it again.

Comment: That might just be it. Since I store that data in database, I could also store date and time downloaded. on each app start I check the time stored and if it has been more than 24h I download it again. thanks

Comment: You should store the date the data was generated, not downloaded. e.g. say it is produced at midnight every night and I download at 11 PM it should check again for me after an hour. This is simpler to implement as there is only one date for each version of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `Shared Preferences` storage option provided by Android platform to store last access information and then act accordingly.
For more details refer this link: [Android developer reference for Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)